# How to make a post call to a Web Api Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've created a Web API Action as below

```
[HttpPost]
public void Load(string siteName, string providerName, UserDetails userDetails)
{
// implementation
}
```

The route I've registered for this is as below (not sure if it's correct?):

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "loadUserDetails",
             routeTemplate: "sites/{siteName}/User/Load/{providerName}/{userDetailsList}",
             defaults: new
             {
                 controller = "User",
                 action = "Load",
                 providerName = UrlParameter.Optional
             });
```

The providerName parameter should be optional and I'm using Xml Serialization.

The action should response to the below url sample:

```
http://www.domain.com/sites/site1/user/load/provider1/[some user details in the post]
or
http://www.domain.com/sites/site1/user/load/[some user details in the post]
```

How could I make a post call to this action so that I can test my service?

Comment: Doesn't optional parameter need a default value?

Comment: yes, but it can be set later; the post won't call this action like a c# class. the default provider is loaded from the web.config later.

Answer (score 3):

From: [HTTP request with post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)

```
HttpWebRequest request =
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http:\\domain.com\page.asp");

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = "username=user";
postData += "&password=pass";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: the original postdata you're sending, shouldn't it be in the xml format? also if I have another UserDetails userDetails input parameter how does it know to which parameter it should be assigning it to?!

Comment: How would you send a more complex xml data?

Comment: Are you trying to make an raw post?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to test your action, you can use [Fidler](http://fiddler2.com/).

See http://www.mehdi-khalili.com/fiddler-in-action/part-2

Answer (score 0):

See the response from here using RestSharp and Web Request:

http://pooyakhamooshi.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-post-request-to-web-api-web.html